# removing indels in plink

Tags: plink

I have data in Plink format. I removed Indels using --snps-only command in Plink, but still some snps are as below:

```
rs58119544;rs5746975    0   16915280    T   A
```

I wonder, how i can get rid of these snps? the correct should be single snps without this (;) sign. Any idea to fix it please?

Comment: Hello, I have been trying to figure out what is plink format and it seems that it does not really exist. There are a [lot of plink-flavoured formats](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/formats). Could you [edit] your question and be more specific? Maybe it would be also useful if you would write why are the lines with ";" a problem. If you just want to keep lines without semicolon, you can just do `grep -v ";" my_plink_file > filtered_plink_file`.

Answer (score 1):

Use *grep* to get SNPs that have `";"` in the name:

```
>$ grep ";" myMap.txt | cut -f1 -d" " > myBadSNPs.txt
```

Then use plink with [--exclude](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/filter#snp) :

```
plink --file myFile
--exclude myBadSNPs.txt
--out myFileFiltered
```